# OpenSSL AES works only on certain machine, even with static linking

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl, aes

I use OpenSSL 1.1.1 for AES decryption on Linux. It works on my machine, but doesn't work on another, so I used static linking. It didn't help. Here's a code:

```cpp
    if (EVP_DecryptInit(ctx.get(), EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256(), _key.impl.data(),
                        nullptr) != 1)
    {
        const char* errorString = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr);
        return out;
    }
```

on the machine where it doesn't work, the errorString is following:

```
error:0607B083:digital envelope routines:EVP_CipherInit_ex:no cipher set
```

ldd on my `*.so` file confirms it is linked statically:

```
ldd mylib.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe971a9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa3a3b64000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa3a395c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa3a373d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa3a33b4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa3a3016000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa3a2dfe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa3a2a0d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa3a445b000)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have just discovered that `EVP_aes_256_cbc` returns the same result as `EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256` and several others. What is the difference between those then?

My goal is to replace WinAPI `CryptAcquireContextW(&cryptProv_, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_W,PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)`

`EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256()` returns nullptr, `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` returns correct object and works on both machines.

Comment: If that was a linking problem, you program wouldn't even run. How do you set the cipher on first computer? Can you compare `openssl.cnf` of both computer?

Comment: @Mathieu I meant shared object could be different in each computers. With static linking that problem should not exists.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why cramming four function calls into one line such as `if (EVP_DecryptInit(ctx.get(), EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256(), _key.impl.data(),
                        nullptr) != 1)` is a really bad idea.  Of those four function calls, you simply can not tell which one went bad.  How do you know it's not `ctx.get()` or even `_key.impl.data()` that's failing on some systems and causing cascading failures?  You **can't** tell.  But if you made each call separately, checking **every** call for success and logging failures, you'd know. 10 LOC for an unsolvable problem? Bad.

Comment: Are you getting exactly the same error with "EVP_aes_256_cbc()"?, i.e. the "no cipher set" error? The *only* reason that is ever returned from EVP_DecryptInit is if your input cipher is NULL, i.e. "EVP_aes_256_cbc()" returns NULL (you could add some debugging to confirm if that is the case or not). If that is happening then something has gone badly wrong somewhere...

Comment: @AndrewHenle `EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256()` returns nullptr, which is what error message says.

Comment: And you can't tell why.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256()`. This is a highly specialised cipher that is not intended for general use. It is intended to only be used by libssl. The documentation for it is on this page:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256.html

The most relevant section on that page says this about the cipher:

> Authenticated encryption with AES in CBC mode using SHA256 (SHA-2, 256-bits) as HMAC, with keys of 128 and 256 bits length respectively. The authentication tag is 256 bits long.
>
> WARNING: this is not intended for usage outside of TLS and requires calling of some undocumented ctrl functions. These ciphers do not conform to the EVP AEAD interface.

In other words if you do not understand the details of the undocumented aspects of this cipher then do not touch it. One of those undocumented aspects is that it is not supported on all platforms. On some platforms `EVP_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha256()` just returns NULL, e.g. see:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/1bf29d497e66efef0fbc9b1864d8a5db64bf898e/crypto/evp/e_aes_cbc_hmac_sha256.c#L934-L950

This is the most likely reason why it works for you on some machines, but not on others.